# Slam_gmapping stop at Registering First Scan

Tags: slam, navigation, stageros, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I am study using Slam_gmapping.
I ran roscore, stage_ros first. These are the list of topic:

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rostopic list
/base_pose_ground_truth
/base_scan
/clock
/cmd_vel
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

Then I run gmapping and it stop at Registering First Scan

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan
[ INFO] [1459395266.430914447, 120.700000000]: Laser is mounted upwards.
 -maxUrange 29.99 -maxUrange 29.99 -sigma     0.05 -kernelSize 1 -lstep 0.05 -lobsGain 3 -astep 0.05
 -srr 0.1 -srt 0.2 -str 0.1 -stt 0.2
 -linearUpdate 1 -angularUpdate 0.5 -resampleThreshold 0.5
 -xmin -100 -xmax 100 -ymin -100 -ymax 100 -delta 0.05 -particles 30
[ INFO] [1459395266.459964049, 120.700000000]: Initialization complete
update frame 0
update ld=0 ad=0
Laser Pose= 0.05 0 0
m_count 0
Registering First Scan
```

I also tried with tutorial in this link but I still have same problem
http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#record

Please let me know if I missed anything? Or any suggestion the method to track the problem are welcome.
I run ROS on Jetson TX1

Edit 1

I have just attached the tf tree and below is some info from base-scan
[image: image description]

```
 header: 
      seq: 259
      stamp: 
        secs: 26
        nsecs: 0
      frame_id: base_laser_link
    angle_min: -2.35837626457
    angle_max: 2.35837626457
    angle_increment: 0.00436736317351
    time_increment: 0.0
    scan_time: 0.0
    range_min: 0.0
    range_max: 30.0
    ranges: [2.454775333404541, 2.446903944015503, 2.4644339084625244, ...
    intensities: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, ...
```

Edit 2:

rqt_graph [image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230608/slam_gmapping-stop-at-registering-first-scan/) by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2016-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-04-01**:
If you run rostopic echo /base_scan do you get any output?

Also what does your TF tree look like?

Mark

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-04-01**:
Mark, Thanks for your help. I have just edited my question to included header of /base-scan and tf tree screen shot.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2016-04-02**:
Can you post the rqtgraph result? Just to understand if every msg is connected in the right way

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-04-02**:
Walter, I added the rqt_graph pics. Thank you.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-03**:
Is the robot moving? `slam_gmapping` has two parameters (`linearUpdate`, `angularUpdate`) that determine how much the robot has to translate or rotate before the algorithm executes another iteration.

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-04-04**:
spmaniato: You answered my question. When I saw it hang at Registering First Scan, I didn't try to continue moving the robot by keyboard. But when I try it, after a delay, the gmapping start process with status update. Could you please changed this to answer so I can accept. Thank you very much.

**Comment by [Thang Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25138/thang-nguyen/) on 2016-04-04**:
spmaniato: You answered my question. When I saw it hang at Registering First Scan, I didn't try to continue moving the robot by keyboard. But when I try it, after a delay, the gmapping start process with status update. Could you please changed this to answer so I can accept? Thank you very much.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-04-04**:
Awesome! I posted a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the robot moving in Stage? `slam_gmapping` has two parameters (`linearUpdate`, `angularUpdate`) that determine how much the robot has to translate or rotate before the algorithm executes another iteration (see http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)

So you can drive the robot around and/or set those parameters to `0.0` in order to trigger the SLAM process.

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan _linearUpdate:=0.0 _angularUpdate:=0.0
```

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2